# HyperLinks not rendering in the output

Tags: html, asp.net, css

New to ASP.NET and pulling my hair out with this issue. The following ASP.NET code does not render the List Items (HyperLinks that is) in the output:

```
<div class="menu-box">
    <ul>
        <li><asp:HyperLink CssClass="a4 active" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/AllUsers.aspx" ID="lnkAllUsers">All Users</asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink CssClass="a3 active" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/UploadReportMain.aspx" ID="lnkExtractions">Extractions</asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink CssClass="a2 active" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Register.aspx" ID="lnkRegisterUser">Register User</asp:HyperLink></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The output is this:

```
<div class="menu-box">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

The CSS is different for each a1, a2 etc. I'm copying just one of them.

```
.a2 {
display:block;
/*background:url(../images/products.jpg) center top no-repeat;*/
text-transform:uppercase;
padding-top:18px;
} 
.a2:hover, .a2.active {
color:#14A1ED;
display:block;
/*background:url(../images/products-h.jpg) center top no-repeat;*/
}
```

CSS for menu-box:

```
.menu-box {
float: right;
width: 450px;
font-family:'Open Sans';
padding-top:25px;
}
.menu-box ul li {
float: right;
display:block;
padding-left:45px;
}
```

Comment: what is the css for `active` class?

Comment: check you two css classed for `display:none;` or `visibility` `a4 and active`

Comment: it would good if you put your css as well

Comment: where is the `active` class of css??

Comment: Sorry Shekhar, I'm new to CSS as well. Doesn't `.a2.active` represent the class you're asking for?

Comment: @dotNET: .a2 and .active are supposed to be two different classes. if not, then your css should read `.a2:active` if you are after the active pseudo-class.

Comment: This isn't a CSS issue if your HTML elements aren't even being rendered

Comment: @Curt: You are right on spot. See my comment in Shekhar's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one was of created name classes for anchor tag

```
a.column:link {color: #009900;}
a.column:visited {color: #999999;}
a.column:hover {color: #333333;}
a.column:focus {color: #333333;}
a.column:active {color: #009900;}



<asp:HyperLink CssClass="column" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Register.aspx" ID="lnkRegisterUser">
 Register User</asp:HyperLink>
```

or modify your css as follows

```
.menu-box a {
display:block;
/*background:url(../images/products.jpg) center top no-repeat;*/
text-transform:uppercase;
padding-top:18px;
} 
.menu-box a:hover, .menu-box a:active {
color:#14A1ED;
display:block;
/*background:url(../images/products-h.jpg) center top no-repeat;*/
} 


.menu-box {
float: right;
width: 450px;
font-family:'Open Sans';
padding-top:25px;
}
.menu-box ul li {
float: right;
display:block;
padding-left:45px;
}
```

and remove css classes for hyperlink

```
<div class="menu-box">
    <ul>
        <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/AllUsers.aspx" ID="lnkAllUsers">All Users</asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/UploadReportMain.aspx" ID="lnkExtractions">Extractions</asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Register.aspx" ID="lnkRegisterUser">Register User</asp:HyperLink></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Shekhar. It turned out that a piece of code-behind was actually turning off the visibility of these hyperlinks. HTML and CSS were just fine for that matter. But your comments and answer did help me learn something new about CSS today. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
<asp:HyperLink CssClass="a4 active" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/AllUsers.aspx" ID="lnkAllUsers">All Users</asp:HyperLink>
```

use this

```
<asp:HyperLink CssClass="a4 active" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/AllUsers.aspx" ID="lnkAllUsers" Text="All Users"></asp:HyperLink>
```